# How to put the captured screenshot into folder with the Applescript?

Tags: applescript

am trying to capture screenshot and dump into folder on the desktop with the applescript..
i was successful in taking the screenshot but not dumping into folder which is not existing on the desktop.. Pls suggest..

I tried..

```
set loc to "/Users/username/Desktop/New Folder"
property N : 0
set N to N + 1
set picPath to (loc & "Picture_" & N & ".png") as string
do shell script "screencapture -tjpg " & quoted form of picPath
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first line (set loc...) add the following line:

```
do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of loc
```

Comment: Did you get any error? Post the Applescript editor log and the script you used.

Comment: am not getting any errors.. sorry folder is getting created but image is been posted in the desktop not in the folder..  set loc to "/Users/rajasekaranr/Desktop/New Folder123"
do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of loc
property N : 0
set N to N + 1
set picPath to (loc & "Picture_" & N & ".png") as string
do shell script "screencapture -tjpg " & quoted form of picPath

Comment: Add a slash at the end of the loc path: set loc to "/Users/username/Desktop/New Folder/"